# Problem in units convertion when multipliying Boltzmann constant and a temperature

Tags: units

When define the temperature of a variable in Celsius, Mathematica 9.0 does not calculate the right answer when multiplying by boltzmann constant.

Example:

```
Temperature1 = Quantity[100, "Celsius"];

Temperature2 = Quantity[373.15, "Kelvins"];

Temperature1 * Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"]

Temperature2 * Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"]
```

> ```
> Quantity[1.38065*10^-21, "Joules"] <-- WRONG Answer
>
> Quantity[5.15189*10^-21, "Joules"] <-- CORRECT Answer
> ```

*Mathematica* should be able to manage this units conversion,
or there is something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can send a bug report [to support@wolfram.com](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback) ¯\\(°_o)/¯

Comment: What version are you using, I have got different output on V9.010

Comment: I have the same version V9.010

Comment: For me it doesn't compute, I get `Quantity[373.15,Times["BoltzmannConstant","Kelvins"]]`. Am I supposed to do something more with this to get it in Joules?

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the fact that I don't get the same results using *Mathematica* 9.0.1.0...

From the [tutorial on temperature units](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TemperatureUnits.html):

> When working with absolute temperatures, it is imperative to first standardize the units, to allow for proper unit conversions.

In this case it appears that you have to standardise both your temperatures and $k_b$ to obtain the result that you expect, i.e.

```
UnitConvert[Temperature1, "Kelvins"] UnitConvert[Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"],"Joules"/"Kelvins"]

(* 5.15189*10^-21 J *)
```

Comment: Thank you. My bad,  I thought that mathematica would handle everything on its own. This is very tricky when having multiple variables and functions with different units.

Comment: @Pedro - I sympathise, although it is a useful feature in practice it is difficult to use correctly -- especially when absolute temperatures are present. PS An up-vote is usually considered thanks enough!

Comment: Ok. I received an answer from Wolfram Technical Support. They are stating that this is a bug and that they are sending and incident report to the developers.

Comment: This is a better way to see the error:                      
t1 = Quantity[100, "Celsius"];
t2 = Quantity[327.15, "Kelvins"];
kk = Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"];
UnitSimplify[(t1*kk)]
UnitSimplify[(t2*kk)]

Comment: Any updates on this?